# How to implement b-collapse with v-if directive?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vuejs2

I have a sidebar in my mobile view. I have to render the `b-collapse` conditionally. The condition is this: If I have an `options` array of objects in my `subCategory` array of objects, then `b-collapse` should be rendered. My `b-collapse` is inside of `b-list-group-item` that is rendered by the `v-for`

I tried to access the options in this way: 
`v-if="category[0].subCategory[0].options"`

Template:

```
<b-list-group :key="option1.id" v-for="option1 in category">
        <b-list-group-item ><span>{{ option1.title }}</span></b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item v-b-toggle.collapse-1 @click.stop="toShow" class="subCategory" role="button" 
          :key="option2.id" v-for="option2 in option1.subCategory">
          <!-- Подкатегории -->
          <a>{{ option2.title }}</a>
          <b-collapse id="collapse-1" v-if="category[0].subCategory[0].options">
            <b-list-group class="d-md-none d-lg-none d-sm-block" :key="option1.id" >
              <ul class="list-group" :key="option2.id" v-for="option2 in option1.subCategory">
                <router-link class="list-group-item" to="formProperty" :key="option3.id" v-for="option3 in option2.options">
                  <!-- Опций -->
                  {{ option3.title }}
                </router-link>         
              </ul>
      </b-list-group>
    </b-collapse>      
  </b-list-group-item>
</b-list-group>
```

Data:

```
category : [
          {
            "title" : "ФИЗ.ЛИЦАМ",
            subCategory: [
              {
                "title"  : "НАЛОГИ",
                "options": [
                  { "title" : 'НАЛОГ НА ИМУЩЕСТВО' },
                  { "title" : 'НАЛОГ НА ИМУЩЕСТВО(ПЕНИ)' },
                  { "title" : 'ЗЕМЕЛЬНЫЙ НАЛОГ' },
                  { "title" : 'ЗЕМЕЛЬНЫЙ НАЛОГ(ПЕНИ)' },
                  { "title" : 'СОЦИАЛЬНЫЙ НАЛОГ' },
                  { "title" : 'СОЦИАЛЬНЫЙ НАЛОГ(ПЕНИ)' },
                  { "title" : 'ИПН НЕОБЛАГАЕМЫЙ' },
                  { "title" : 'ИПН НЕОБЛАГАЕМЫЙ(ПЕНИ)' },
                  { "title" : 'ИПН ОБЛАГАЕМЫЙ' },
                  { "title" : 'ИПН ОБЛАГАЕМЫЙ(ПЕНИ)' }
                ]
              },
              {
                "title": "ШТРАФЫ",
                "id": 19,
                "url": "/form/19"
              },
              {
                "title" : "СОЦИАЛЬНЫЕ ОТЧИСЛЕНИЯ",
                "id" : 18,
                "url" : "/form/203"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? How does the current behaviour differ from the behaviour that you'd want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `v-if="option2.options"` instead of `v-if="category[0].subCategory[0].options"`